# Solving for a stationary point of a multivariate Gaussian parameter (CCA)

Tags: statistics, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am reading a paper, [probabilistic CCA](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/probacca.pdf), and am stuck on a particular derivation. Given the following multivariate Gaussian:

$$
x \sim N(u, W W^{\top} + P)
$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$. Let $S = W W^{\top} + P$ where $S \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$.

Given the negative log-likelihood, $L$:

$$
L
=
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - u)^{\top} S^{-1} (x_i - u) + \frac{n}{2} \ln |S| + \text{const}
$$

Taking the derivative, I have a stationary point $\frac{dL}{dW} = 0$, and I would like to solve for $W$ (Equation 3 in the paper):

$$
(S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^{\top} S^{-1}) W = 0
$$

where $Z = (x - u)$. How can I solve for $W$? I can reduce it to this form:

$$
\begin{align}
(S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^{\top} S^{-1}) W &= 0
\\
S^{-1} W - S^{-1} Z Z^{\top} S^{-1} W &= 0
\\
S^{-1} W &= S^{-1} Z Z^{\top} S^{-1} W
\\
W &= Z Z^{\top} S^{-1} W
\end{align}
$$

This looks like an eigenvector problem, $A v = \lambda v$, but $S^{-1}$ contains $W$:

$$
W = Z Z^{\top} (WW^{\top} + P) W
$$

I'm not sure how to simplify this further.

Comment: Are you trying to find the value of $W$ that minimizes $L$ with $P$ fixed? $\qquad$

Comment: Yeah. I can prove that $P = \frac{1}{n}(ZZ^{\top} - WW^{\top})$ at the stationary point $\frac{dL}{dP} = 0$. Note that in the paper, Theorem 2, the claim is that $P  = (ZZ^{\top} - WW^{\top})$, but I don't know where the $\frac{1}{n}$ goes.